# extract unknown from different format string

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have a excel file with a column populated with lots of values. I want to extract only the name from the field, but the problem is though the excel format is the same, the values differ from company to company... as one company's excel column looks as follow

```
Name S/N-ABC000ED0
Name Surname S/N-ABE00CD00
```

and the other company

```
ABC/Name/00
CDF/Name/10
```

I need to account for both types of format in my application, But I Have no idea how to write this method

```
public static string CleanUp(string name)
{
....
....

return name
}
```

Comment: You do not show any issues or any kind of examples of what you have tried. Also your question is a little unclear. I might suggest you that you have to handle the cleanup manually for each company as you say it comes `unknown` which also kinda means `unpredictable` unless you know what format each company comes with then simply write functionality for each of that and depending on the company you call the corresponding function.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that these will be the only two formats you can do something like this:

```
//1st Case
if (dirtyString.Contains(" "))
    cleanString = dirtyString.Split(' ')[0];
//2nd Case
else
    cleanString = dirtyString.Split('/')[1];
```

There's many ways of doing this. You could use RegEx if you wanted, but this approach will work if you know for a fact these are the only two formats.

Comment: I just wanted to note that *Name* is an arbitrary string provided by OP, most probably it contains spaces. You answer is like a Schrödinger's cat dilemma: it can be right and it can be wrong at the same time :)

Comment: @stribizhev Yes you're right. It's impossible for us to know if the name can contain spaces or not. It most likely could - but this is something that OP will have to figure out on his own. There's an infinite amount of resources already on SO regarding these kind of situations.